# Accessing files outside root directory

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1

I've installed magento and cakephp in my development server. I built a STL viewer by using cake php and gave path like this to upload files to STL viewer:

```
$mystlpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."dastl/app/webroot/uploads/".$filetoinsertpost;
```

Now I want STL viewer to access STL files stored in magento directory. It is like accessing files from different directory which is outside root directory. How can I give a path so that STL viewer can access stl files from magento directory?
Can I try like this?

```
$mystlpath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../path_to_magento/".$filetoinsertpost;
```

Here is file structure to make this question more clear:

```
server root directory
           |www
               |dastl
               |magento
```

Comment: Are you trying to load your files from Magento into STL or the other way around?

Comment: Trying to load from magento to STL

Comment: So this really isn't a Magento question.

Comment: That is why I asked it in webmasters.stackexchange and it was migrated here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149483/get-folder-up-one-level) you can do:

```
dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Or:

```
dirname(__FILE__) . '/..';
```

...but in a web server environment you will probably find that you are already working from current file's working directory, so you can probably just use:

```
'../'
```

...to reference the directory above. You can also replace dirname(**FILE**) with **DIR** from PHP 5.3.0 onwards

Comment: I tried ..\ method, it didn't work. Should try `dirname()` method

Comment: Dont use \, try with /. Its not the same.

Comment: Yeah, I tried ../, it didn't work. This is the error which I got: failed to open stream, no such directory

Comment: Can you tell me more accurately that how can I use it?

Comment: Try this die(var_dump($_SERVER)) and paste it here. We are looking for $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] exactly.

Comment: Check this link: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=a24f5d8

Comment: Perfect. Try this $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'path_to_magento/'.$filetoinsertpost;

Comment: Not working. Check this link: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=72b46fe

Comment: Where is the file located? The complete path from /www/

Comment: I got it, thank you.... This was the first time that I was referring a file outside root directory, so got confused.